# Ruby: Prefill New Model Form From Previous Page's Partial Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

Ruby on Rails, Simple Form.

I have a contact/Message partial on several pages (product#index#show, static ‘services’ page) — when someone fills out the partial form and submits, I want the Message#new page to load with partial data prefilling the larger contact form without creating a new message and sending the action mailer.

Other SO solutions are for multi-step forms, wizards, or passing data through URL.

Here's my code:

**_Shortcontact (the partial)**

```
<div class="short_contact_wrapper">
  <h4 id="short_container_title">Contact Us</h4>
  <div class="contact-container">
    <%= simple_form_for(message) do |f| %>
    <div class="form-row-2">
      <%= f.input :contactfirstname, label: false, placeholder: "* First Name", presence: true, :input_html => { :class => 'input_string' } %>
      <%= f.input :contactlastname, label: false, placeholder: "* Last Name" %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row-2">
      <%= f.input :email, label: false, placeholder:"* Email" %>
      <%= f.input :phone, label: false, placeholder: "* Phone" %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="contact-container">
    <%= f.input :product_app, label: "Product Application Category",  collection: ["Drones", "5G Telecom", "Thin Battery", "Auto Warehouse", "Robotics", "Wearables", "Electric Vehicles", "Industrial Personal Computers (Military)", "Industrial Personal Computers(Medical)", "Consumer Electronics", "Uninterruptible Power System", "Internet of Things", "Power Bank", "Other" ] %>
    <%= f.input :batteryapp, label: false, placeholder: "Please describe the product and how you\'ll use the lithium ion battery or cell." %>
    <div class="bottom_container" style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
      <%= f.button :submit, "Submit", class: 'contactbutton' %>

    </div>
     <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**In my Product controller #Edit and #Show:**

```
before_action :build_message, only: [:index, :new, :show]

def index
    @products = Product.all
  end

  def new
    @product = Product.new
    # build nested models
    @product.product_specs.build
    @product.specifications.build

  end

  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_parameters)
    @product.category_id = product_parameters[:category_id]

    # setting product stuff for TESTING
    @product.picture = "products/IPC_tablet.png"
    @product.iconblack = "icons/products/icon_IPC_black.png"

    if @product.save!
      flash[:success] = "You have saved the #{@product.name} product"
      redirect_to product_path(@product)
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "Product was not saved"
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def show
    @product_specs = @product.product_specs
  end

  def edit
      # build nested models
    @product.product_specs.build
    @product.specifications.build
  end

def build_message
    @message = Message.new
  end
```

**Message Controller**

```
def new
    @message = Message.new
    @message.build_company

    puts "#{params[:message].inspect}"
    puts "are there parameters?"
    puts "#{@message.inspect}"
  end

  def create
    @message = Message.new(message_parameters)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @message.save!
        #send through mailer
        MessageMailer.send_message(@message).deliver_now
        format.html {redirect_to message_path(@message)}
      else
        format.html {render action: 'new'}
        format.json {render json: @message.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**Edit: Example of where I call _shortform: Layout/products **

```
<%= render '/partials/head' %>
<%= render '/partials/header' %>
<%= render 'layouts/messages' %>

<div class="product_layout_container">
<div class="layout_sidebar">
  <%= link_to products_path do %>
    <h4>Products</h4>
  <% end %>
  <%= render 'products/productsidebar', locals: {products: @products, categories: @categories } %>
</div>



  <div class="product_yield">
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="page_container bottom_container">
  <% unless user_signed_in? %>
    <%= render partial: 'messages/shortcontact', locals: { message: @message }%>
  <% end %>
</div>



 <%= render '/partials/footer' %>
 <%= render '/partials/foot' %>
```

I need help figuring out how to structure my partial form, or how I can prefill the Message#new form.... Thanks!

Comment: This is a side note but should use `if @message.save` not `if @message.save!`. `save!` raises an exception if the record is not valid which is uncaught. Ideally one of your tests should have already told you this.

Comment: Hi Max! Thanks, I'm currently using save! to view the errors

Comment: Could you post the view code where `_Shortcontact` is called please? One example of this should be sufficient.

Comment: Hi @srack, Yes I added the code under Edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by adding [an additional route](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions) (POST /messages/new):

```
resources :messages do
  post :new, on: :collection
end
```

This is somewhat optional. Its possible to just setup this up with just GET as well but the parameters will be sent in the URL.

You can then simply bind the parameters to the model instance via strong the strong parameters.

```
class MessagesController
  # ...
  def new
    @message = Message.new
    # We need a condition here to avoid a parameter missing error
    @message.assign_attributes(message_parameters) if params[:message]
  end
end
```

You also have to manually override the path of the form:

```
simple_form_for(message, url: new_message_path)
```

Comment: Actually now when I'm on the main form page trying to submit it just keeps rerendering a new form instead of creating...

Comment: Yeah, you have to actually have different forms or wrap ´url: new_message_path´ in a conditional so that it posts to the correct path.

Comment: I solved it by renaming the route 'prefill_message_path' and then providing a url for the main message form 'new_message_path' ... thanks!